# How can I force GDB to execute code for which there are no symbols

Tags: assembly, gdb, mprotect

I have a C program that (for good reason) allocates memory, copies some code to it, uses mprotect() to give it execute privileges, and then calls that code.
Yes I know this is unportable and unsafe, but there's a good reason.
Anyway, I need to single-step with gdb through the assembly code (using si command) but it won't let me -- it keeps saying:
"No function contains program counter for selected frame"

Is there a way to force gdb to execute this code?  Is there another debugger that I should be using instead for this type of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want the `add-symbol-file', or`add-symbol-file-from-memory' commands
to let gdb know about the code that has been copied to that memory location.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow through your code by using `display/i $pc` before starting to `si` / `stepi`.  This tells it to show the disassembly of the current instruction just before printing the prompt each time.

Answer (score 0):

The `stepi` command itself doesn't require any symbols and should work *just fine* in the scenario you described (though I haven't actually checked whether it does).

Is your problem *really* with `stepi`? Showing relevant part(s) of your debug session might open your question to better answers.